# Google Home: Scheduling Google Actions For Playing Audio or Casting Audio Programatically

Tags: android, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Using a Google Home device, I'd like to develop an app that allows one to schedule an action i.e. "Ok Google, set an [insert app/action name here] alarm for 7:00AM" and have it either:

- Trigger a server audio streaming API at a future date.
- Query a custom API and have it attach an audio link to the existing Google Home alarm action.
- Connect to our existing Android app which could cast its audio to the Google Home programatically at the future date.

I have read through the documentation, and I'm not aware that this is currently possible, but maybe there is:

- An alternative work-around I haven't considered.
- A plan to expand the current Google Home API to allow this.
- A procedure for getting a service like this verified to appear alongside the current Google Home alarm action.

**TL;DR**: Using Google Home, how can I or when will it be possible to, schedule an action to stream custom audio (or cast to Google Home from an installed Android app) at a future date.

Comment: So you're basically looking for some sort of notifications API?

Comment: @NickFelker I suppose so :) So long as the "notification" it triggers enables more functionality than the Android notification system, like streaming audio.

Comment: Unfortunately the current [notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates) API is in developer preview, and even when it is ready it probably will not have streaming capability by default. I'm not sure it'd be a good user experience either to have something start playing out of nowhere.

Comment: @NickFelker The particular use case I'm looking at is for setting an alarm, so it makes sense for it to start playing out of nowhere, like the built in Google Home alarm action currently does.